# Try to convert ids to strings with a switch case in React / Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a beginner's problem. Maybe someone could help me.
I am using an API of movies (TheMovieDb) and I try to convert the genres_ids to strings. The API returns ids for categories instead of labels, or names.
So I have created a switch case in which each id corresponds to its category (ex: '28' corresponding to 'Action')but I can't use it in my component.

Here is my constructor:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      films: [],
      page: 1,
      loading: false,
      genre: null
    };
}
```

Here is my function:

```
buildGenres(state, val) {
    if (state === 'genre') {
      val = convertGenres(val);
    }
    this.setState({ [state]: val });
  }
```

Here is my Switch case:

```
module.exports = {
  convertGenres: (genre) => {
    switch (genre) {
    case '12':
      return'Adventure';
    case '16':
      return'Animation';
    case '28':
      return'Action';
    case '35':
      return'Comedy';
    case '80':
      return'Crime';
    case '99':
      return'Documentary';
    case '18':
      return'Drama';
    case '10751':
      return'Family';
    case '14':
      return'Fantasy';
    case '36':
      return'History';
    case '27':
      return'Horror';
    case '10402':
      return'Music';
    case '9648':
      return'Mystery';
    case '10749':
      return'Romance';
    case '878':
      return'Science Fiction';
    case '10770':
      return'TV Movie';
    case '53':
      return'Thriller';
    case '10752':
      return'War';
    case '37':
      return'Western';
    default:
      return genre;
    }
  }
};
```

And I try to use this in my component with a .map but I can get ids with only film.genre_ids in Tooltip title.
how to do "if genre_ids = 28" then the genre is "Action":

```
const theMovies = this.state.films.map((film, index) => {
      return(<Tooltip 
                    TransitionComponent={Zoom}
                    id="Add to favorite"
                    title={<p>Category:{film.genre_ids}</p>}
                    placement={window.innerWidth > 959 ? "top" : "top"}
                  >
                    <AppsIcon className={classes.iconsHover} />
             </Tooltip>)})
```

I'm really not sure I'm using the right method, so if you have a better idea, I'd be very grateful .
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Do you use your `convertGenres` utility anywhere? Maybe add it to your title: `<P>Categories: {film.genre_ids.map( id => convertGenres( id ).join(', ')}`

Comment: Hi @Greg, nope, finally I'm not using convertGenres utility anywhere but the method of Anuja: `const stringIds = Object.freeze({ '12' :'Adventure', '16' : 'Animation', ...})` with `const getConvertGenres = (genre) => stringIds[genre] ? stringIds[genre] : genre` ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Genres will not be dynamic if you use switch case, if TheMovieDb change anything in there genres category then you might have to update your code and add a new case statement.

There is a separate API to get the genre `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key=<YOUR_API_KEY_HERE>&language=en-US` list which return an Array of Objects like this:

```
let genres = [{
  "id": 28,
  "name": "Action"
},
{
  "id": 12,
  "name": "Adventure"
}]
```

I have a working example of code which returns all the matching genres name according to `genre_ids`

```js
class TheTmdbApp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            movies : [ {
                "popularity": 59.54,
                "vote_count": 792,
                "video": false,
                "poster_path": "\/8j58iEBw9pOXFD2L0nt0ZXeHviB.jpg",
                "id": 466272,
                "adult": false,
                "backdrop_path": "\/kKTPv9LKKs5L3oO1y5FNObxAPWI.jpg",
                "original_language": "en",
                "original_title": "Once Upon a Time in Hollywood",
                "genre_ids": [28, 35, 80, 18, 37],
                "title": "Once Upon a Time in Hollywood",
                "vote_average": 7.6,
                "overview": "A faded television actor and his stunt double strive to achieve fame and success in the film industry during the final years of Hollywood's Golden Age in 1969 Los Angeles.",
                "release_date": "2019-07-26"
            }, {
                "popularity": 45.265,
                "vote_count": 526,
                "video": false,
                "poster_path": "\/hgWAcic93phg4DOuQ8NrsgQWiqu.jpg",
                "id": 452832,
                "adult": false,
                "backdrop_path": "\/oOROXoQ402tHgK6NowmMUSLffkW.jpg",
                "original_language": "en",
                "original_title": "Serenity",
                "genre_ids": [9648, 53],
                "title": "Serenity",
                "vote_average": 5.2,
                "overview": "Baker Dill is a fishing boat captain leading tours off a tranquil, tropical enclave called Plymouth Island. His quiet life is shattered, however, when his ex-wife Karen tracks him down with a desperate plea for help.",
                "release_date": "2019-01-25"
            }, {
                "popularity": 50.454,
                "vote_count": 113,
                "video": false,
                "poster_path": "\/vOl6shtL0wknjaIs6JdKCpcHvg8.jpg",
                "id": 567609,
                "adult": false,
                "backdrop_path": "\/aNrNi5QExO6b8MnEGsfpgp21NIY.jpg",
                "original_language": "en",
                "original_title": "Ready or Not",
                "genre_ids": [27, 9648, 53],
                "title": "Ready or Not",
                "vote_average": 7.5,
                "overview": "A bride's wedding night takes a sinister turn when her eccentric new in-laws force her to take part in a terrifying game.",
                "release_date": "2019-08-21"
            }, {
                "popularity": 46.348,
                "vote_count": 2284,
                "video": false,
                "poster_path": "\/wgQ7APnFpf1TuviKHXeEe3KnsTV.jpg",
                "id": 447404,
                "adult": false,
                "backdrop_path": "\/nDP33LmQwNsnPv29GQazz59HjJI.jpg",
                "original_language": "en",
                "original_title": "Pokémon Detective Pikachu",
                "genre_ids": [28, 12, 14],
                "title": "Pokémon Detective Pikachu",
                "vote_average": 7,
                "overview": "In a world where people collect pocket-size monsters (Pokémon) to do battle, a boy comes across an intelligent monster who seeks to be a detective.",
                "release_date": "2019-05-10"
            }, {
                "popularity": 33.986,
                "vote_count": 45,
                "video": false,
                "poster_path": "\/vVYU0x9FRpiJNX7c54ciFnRBVYG.jpg",
                "id": 441282,
                "adult": false,
                "backdrop_path": "\/6rJAeP8xlq0bHUdCNg5epBvrFVa.jpg",
                "original_language": "en",
                "original_title": "Night Hunter",
                "genre_ids": [80, 9648, 53],
                "title": "Night Hunter",
                "vote_average": 6.1,
                "overview": "A police task force traps an online predator, only to discover that the depth of his crimes goes far beyond anything they had anticipated.",
                "release_date": "2019-09-06"
            }, {
                "popularity": 48.493,
                "vote_count": 1054,
                "video": false,
                "poster_path": "\/f4FF18ia7yTvHf2izNrHqBmgH8U.jpg",
                "id": 504608,
                "adult": false,
                "backdrop_path": "\/oAr5bgf49vxga9etWoQpAeRMvhp.jpg",
                "original_language": "en",
                "original_title": "Rocketman",
                "genre_ids": [18, 10402],
                "title": "Rocketman",
                "vote_average": 7.5,
                "overview": "The story of Elton John's life, from his years as a prodigy at the Royal Academy of Music through his influential and enduring musical partnership with Bernie Taupin.",
                "release_date": "2019-05-31"
            }, {
                "popularity": 46.85,
                "vote_count": 3,
                "video": false,
                "poster_path": "\/eU0orGizEpOli4wtN8HtfOOJDlA.jpg",
                "id": 516700,
                "adult": false,
                "backdrop_path": "\/nmHCKQ1GtlPLZVAtBfsYDqVPhPW.jpg",
                "original_language": "id",
                "original_title": "Gundala",
                "genre_ids": [28, 80, 18],
                "title": "Gundala",
                "vote_average": 8.2,
                "overview": "Sancaka has lived on the streets since his parents left him. Living a hard life, Sancaka survives by thinking about his own safety. When the condition of the city gets worse and injustice rages throughout the country, Sancaka must decide whether he continues to live to look after himself or rise to become their oppressed hero.",
                "release_date": "2019-08-29"
            }],
            genres :
                [
                    {
                        "id": 28,
                        "name": "Action"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 12,
                        "name": "Adventure"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 16,
                        "name": "Animation"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 35,
                        "name": "Comedy"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 80,
                        "name": "Crime"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 99,
                        "name": "Documentary"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 18,
                        "name": "Drama"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 10751,
                        "name": "Family"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 14,
                        "name": "Fantasy"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 36,
                        "name": "History"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 27,
                        "name": "Horror"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 10402,
                        "name": "Music"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 9648,
                        "name": "Mystery"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 10749,
                        "name": "Romance"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 878,
                        "name": "Science Fiction"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 10770,
                        "name": "TV Movie"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 53,
                        "name": "Thriller"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 10752,
                        "name": "War"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 37,
                        "name": "Western"
                    }
                ]

        }
    }

    getMovieGenreName(genre_ids){
        let genreIds = []
        let genreNames = []
        let genres = ""
        this.state.genres.forEach((genre,index) => {
            genreIds[index] = genre.id;
            genreNames[index] = genre.name;
        });
      
        genre_ids.forEach((genre) => {
            let genreIndex = genreIds.indexOf(genre);
            let genreName = genreNames[genreIndex];
            genres += genreName + ' . ';
        })
        genres = genres.slice(0, -2);
        return genres
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.movies.map(movie => {

                    return (
                        <div>
                            <h4>{movie.title}</h4>
                            <span>Genres: {this.getMovieGenreName(movie.genre_ids)}</span>
                        </div>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TheTmdbApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
</body>
```

Hope this helps, Happy Coding!!!

Comment: Thanks a lot @DarpanRangari ! I'll try the Anuja's method just above and make periodic queries for changes, although they don't change very often. I'll try your code right after to make it more dynamic.

Comment: @bastienalessandri cheers mate, you feel this answer resolve your query please accept this as a solution by clicking tick icon under vote.

Comment: Finally your answer resolve my query perfectly. Thanks again and have a good evening !

Answer (score 0):

A different approach will be to have an `enum` type object already defined in code,

```
const stringIds = Object.freeze({ '12' :'Adventure', '16' : 'Animation', ...})
```

so you can directly access the `string` ids, from the object as, `stringIds['12'] = 'Adventure'`

for you `default case` you can check if the `number string` id returns `undefined`, if so just use the `genre` as it is. You could also enclose this logic inside a function for ease of usage, like `getConvertGenres`

```
const getConvertGenres = (genre) => stringIds[genre] ? stringIds[genre] : genre
```

so you `map` `render` will be,

```
const theMovies = this.state.films.map((film, index) => {
  return(<Tooltip 
                TransitionComponent={Zoom}
                id="Add to favorite"
                title={<p>Category:{getConvertGenres(film.genre_ids)}</p>}
                placement={window.innerWidth > 959 ? "top" : "top"}
              >
                <AppsIcon className={classes.iconsHover} />
         </Tooltip>)})
```

**Edit**  for multiple id string

```
const getConvertGenresMulti = (genres) => {
  const stringGenres = []
  Object.keys(stringIds).forEach(id => {
      if(genres.contains(id)){
            stringGenres.push(getConvertGenres(id))
            genres.replace(id,'')
        }
     })
    return stringGenres.join(", ")
 }
```

use this function instead of `getConvertGenres` if you have multiple id string.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Anuja but I don't understand how I can use it in my case.. I have to replace my switch by your const stringIds ? and how to replace "film.genre_ids" and assign him his corresponding genre into a .map ?

Comment: you define the `enum` as i said, and also define the function `getConvertGenres`, then inside your `map` function, use for title,
`title={<p>Category:{getConvertGenres(film.genre_ids)}</p>}`

@bastien alessandri

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot @Anuja ! it works very well but I juste have one last little problem:  Some of movies returns many ids like "12163510751". How to separate each ID with a comma ? Knowing that some IDs have more than two numbers (ex: 9648: Mystery, 10749: Romance etc...) Sorry for all these questions and thank you a lot for your time !

Comment: @bastienalessandri
you could do that if you know exactly if any id is not a `substring` of another id, for example say, if, `"12" : "Comedy"` and `"1234" : "Fantasy"`,  and if your `ids` string is  `"1234870"` we cannot exactly determine if the `ids` string contains `"12" : "Comedy"`  or  `"1234" : "Fantasy"`  or a completely different genre.

Having said that, if you can guarantee that no two `ids` contains a `substring` of the other `id`, we can use `Object.keys(stringIds)` to iterate the `stringIds` and check if `idString` contains any of the `ids` we know.

Comment: Indeed, you think of everything @Anuja ! Apparently the API anticipated these cases of duplicates so I think it can working great by this way.

Comment: @bastienalessandri happy to help, approve answer if correct :)

Comment: Finally I used the @DarpanRangari method which works very well in this case, with another request for genres's list. Thanks everyone for your help, you made my day ! Have a nice evening